# No such file or directory - Error Message When Uploading on Open Shift

Tags: php, git, laravel, openshift

I have created a project using `Laravel`, Its working fine on `Localhost` .
I am using following URL in Localhost `http://localhost/prg/public/`, and its working fine. It opens my index page.

I have uploaded the same working project on Open Shift. I rename the `repo` to `old-repo` and upload my project and `rename` it as `repo`.

The project successfully opens the `INDEX` page, but when i click on any link it opens the Error page.

```
PDOException (2002)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or director


Open: /var/lib/openshift/554c70a5e0b8cdc55a00007e/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
```

**CODE**

```
 */
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
    $username = array_get($config, 'username');

    $password = array_get($config, 'password');

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Database connection settings in `app/config/database.php`.

I also had the same problem once, I forgot to change the `host` from `localhost` to `OpenShift Server Address`, also update `Username` and `Password` in the `config` file, if you haven't already.